# Firestore cloud function - how to return second query

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an on-create cloud function where I want to move the data from one container to another. The first query seems to run ok (Im checking data) but the second where I add it seems to be failing, I understand I have to return a promise from cloud functions but it should still return the inner one?

```js
exports.msgMove = functions.firestore.document('/msgTemp/{documentId}')
.onCreate( (snap:any, context:any) => {

  const data = snap.data();

  // Has this user already replied?
  return firestore.collection("msg")
  .where('threadId', '==', snap.data().threadId)
  .where('trackId', '==', snap.data().trackId)
  .where('uid', '==',  snap.data().uid)
  .orderBy("created", "desc")
  .limit(1)
  .get()
  .then(async (query) => {

      if(query.empty){

        const {threadId, trackId, uid} = snap.data();

        // Below seems to be failing
        const add = await firestore.collection("msg").add(
          {
            threadId,
            trackId,
            uid
          }
        );

        return add;

      }

      return;

  })
});
```

Im getting the error:

> {"severity":"WARNING","message":"Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `then()` and `async/await` (`.then(async (query) => {...})`) which is not recommended.

You should do as follows:

#### Using only `then()`

```
exports.msgMove = functions.firestore.document('/msgTemp/{documentId}')
    .onCreate((snap: any, context: any) => {

        const data = snap.data();

        // Has this user already replied?
        return firestore.collection("msg")
            .where('threadId', '==', data.threadId)
            .where('trackId', '==', data.trackId)
            .where('uid', '==', data.uid)
            .orderBy("created", "desc")
            .limit(1)
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                    const { threadId, trackId, uid } = snap.data();

                    return firestore.collection("msg").add(
                        {
                            threadId,
                            trackId,
                            uid
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    return null;
                }

            });
    });
```

We [chain the promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#chaining) returned by the Firebase asynchronous methods by using `then()` (which returns a Promise).

#### Using only `async/await`

```
exports.msgMove = functions.firestore
    .document('/msgTemp/{documentId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap: any, context: any) => {   // <== See the async keyword
   
        const data = snap.data();

        // Has this user already replied?
        const querySnapshot = await firestore
            .collection('msg')
            .where('threadId', '==', data.threadId)
            .where('trackId', '==', data.trackId)
            .where('uid', '==', data.uid)
            .orderBy('created', 'desc')
            .limit(1)
            .get();

        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            const { threadId, trackId, uid } = snap.data();

            await firestore.collection('msg').add({
                threadId,
                trackId,
                uid,
            });
        }
        return null;
    });
```

Comment: async version worked thanks, but I have to change from returning null to:
return Promise.resolve("Finished...");
as you have to return a promise I think

Comment: AFAIK returning `null` (Or another value) is ok, an async function always returns a Promise.

Comment: You may also upvote my answer if it helped you. Thanks.